# What are the commendation voice lines for all heroes?

Tags: overwatch

When a hero gets commended with a specific amount of points, both at 5 votes and at 10 votes they get a special voice line.

For example, when Mercy gets commended at five votes she will say "*It's nice to be appreciated.*"

However, I've never heard her 10 vote line because rarely does everyone in the match vote for the same person.

What are all the commendation voice lines for the heroes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### "Epic" lines (5 commendations):

#### Ana:

- "Someone needs to show how it's done."
- "That is how it's supposed to be done."
- "You made the right decision."

#### Bastion:

- "Whiiiiiiiiiiiirrrrr"

#### D.Va:

- "Ohaha, thanks for the love."
- "Ding!"
- "Thanks for your support!"

#### Genji:

- "Most Enjoyable!"
- "良し！" ("Okay!")

#### Hanzo:

- "Excellence!"
- "You honor me!"

#### Junkrat:

- "Mah genius is finally recognized!"
- "Bring the tears to my eyes."

#### Lucio:

- "Unreal!"
- "Thank you, thank you"

#### McCree:

- "Much obliged"
- "Mighty fine!"

#### Mei:

- "Thumbs Up to That."
- "Thanks everyone!"

#### Mercy:

- "Excellent."
- "It's nice to be appreciated."

#### Orisa:

- unknown

#### Pharah:

- "Mission Accomplished"
- "That's how we do it!"
- "Clear skies ahead."

#### Reaper:

- *laughter*
- "Right..."

#### Reinhardt:

- "That's How Its Done"
- "Vunderful!"
- "Ohoh! Impressive, if I do say so myself!"
- "To see justice done is its own reward."

#### Roadhog:

- "That's More Like It"
- "Easy" ("EZ")

#### Soldier 76:

- "I'm just doing my job."
- "I'm not in it for the glory."
- "Job well done!"
- "That's more like it!"

#### Sombra:

- "I thought so."
- "Someone has to pull their weight around here."

#### Symmetra:

- "A performance worthy of repetition."
- "Ah, that is the way!"

#### Torbjörn:

- "Haha! Right on!"
- "Ironclad!"

#### Tracer:

- "Oh! Thanks love."
- "Sensational!"

#### Widowmaker:

- "Hmm... par excellence!"
- "Umm... I always hit my mark."

#### Winston:

- "It's nice to be appreciated."
- "Impressive"

#### Zarya:

- "100%."
- "Hard work is its own reward."
- "Ура!" ("Hooray!")

#### Zenyatta:

- "Wonderful!"
- "Excellence is its own reward."

---

### "Legendary" lines (10 commendations):

#### Ana:

- "I don't do speeches."
- "When I was younger, we called this routine."

#### Bastion:

- *chirping sounds*

#### D.Va:

- "Save that for the Hall of Fame!"
- "That's the star performance."

#### Genji:

- "It is an honor"
- "It was nothing!"

#### Hanzo:

- "True mastery is the highest art."
- "Strike for perfection."

#### Junkrat:

- "Thank you, thank you, thank you"
- "Hahahahaha! I won! I won! ...What did I win?"

#### Lucio:

- "I make this look easy!"
- "I'm running this show!"

#### McCree:

- "All in a day's work."
- "Time to ride off into the sunset."

#### Mei:

- "Oh, it was nothing... really."
- "Sometimes, I surprise myself."

#### Mercy:

- "I couldn't have done it alone"
- "I am touched by your support."

#### Orisa:

- unknown

#### Pharah:

- "After-action report: 'Unstoppable'."
- "I serve with distinction."

#### Reaper:

- "Finally some recognition"
- "Whatever."
- *laughter*

#### Reinhardt:

- "I am the champion!"
- "What a performance!"

#### Roadhog:

- "Only thing you can count on in this broken world"
- "I'm a prime specimen."

#### Soldier 76:

- "I'll do whatever it takes."
- "Save the medals, I had my fill."
- "You can keep your medals and your commendations."

#### Sombra:

- "Do I win a prize?"
- "It was nothing."

#### Symmetra:

- "Aah, that is the way"

#### Torbjörn:

- "Humhahahaha! Will you take a look at that?"
- What can I say? Best of the best!"

#### Tracer:

- "Excelsior!"
- "Aaaahhh... yeah!"

#### Widowmaker:

- "Hmm, un vrai chef d'oeuvre!" ("Hmm, a real masterpiece!")
- "Perfect!"

#### Winston:

- "I'm just trying to do my part"
- "I gave it my best."

#### Zarya:

- "I do it for my country."
- "One of my best performances!"

#### Zenyatta:

- unknown

[source](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Card)